# How many Chia plots can I fit on a hard drive, when attempting to fill it completely and maximizing the overall number of plots?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, optimization, discrete-optimization

I'm making plots for Chia, a cryptocurrency which isn't "mined" in the strict sense of the word, but instead requires that one have many files known as "plots" on a storage drive (e.g. a hard disk drive). Units of cryptocurrency are primarily awarded based on total space consumed: more free space on a drive means a smaller chance of scoring a win.

The smallest size of plot, known as the "k=32" plot, takes up $101.4$ gibibytes (GiB) of storage. While I can fill a hard drive with that many plots, it doesn't maximize the space on the drive. As an example, if I have a hard drive with $3725.29$ GiB of space (4 terabytes), I can make a maximum of $36$ k=32 plots on it, and still have $74.89$ GiB of space remaining on it.

To help minimize the amount of free space on a drive, I can make larger plot sizes as per the below table:

| Plot type | Space required (GiB) |
| --- | --- |
| k=32 | $101.4$ |
| k=33 | $208.8$ |
| k=34 | $429.8$ |
| k=35 | $884.1$ |

However, even though each successive plot size takes about $2.06$ times as much space as the last, the process of generating a successively larger plot size uses significantly more than that much computing time and energy (exact amount not known). As such, while the most optimal solution to maximize used space is to make as many larger plots as possible, I instead want to make as many small plots as possible, which in turn leads to having as many overall plots as possible.

Given a size of a storage drive in GiB, how can I calculate the best combination of plots to store on the drive, when I want to both get as many overall plots on the drive as I can and end up with as little free space as possible?

Also, what are the best combinations when attempting to meet these concrete goals on hard drive sizes of $3725.29$ GiB and $5587.94$ GiB?

It seems like I'd need to optimize the inequality $101.4a + 208.8b + 429.8c + 884.1d \leq capacity$ for both the maximum value of $a+b+c+d$ and the closest value of $\frac{101.4a + 208.8b + 429.8c + 884.1d}{capacity}$ to $1$. But how can I optimize for both?

Comment: Is number of plots all that really matters when awarding this crypto? Or does total size matter as well? How are these factors weighted? These questions should be answered before we know how we want to optimize the storage. For example, if number of plots is all that matters then you would just add as many $k=32$ plots as you can and "keep" the rest of the storage for yourself. Or better yet, you could run a RAID setup on your drives.

Comment: If the primary concern is overall number of plots, then you have already found the optimal strategy. Since $k=33$ is more than twice the size of $k=32$, there is no way to use a larger plot type without sacrificing number of plots. For example, if you have 101.3 GiB left over on a drive, you cannot switch one plot to another type without decreasing the number of plots. As another example if you have 209 GiB left over, it would be "better" to fill it with 2 $k=32$ plots and have more space left over than to have one $k=33$ plot.

Comment: @vb628 Actually, I did some research and it looks like I was wrong: [total size](https://github.com/Chia-Network/chia-blockchain/wiki/Quick-Start-Guide) is the primary criterion. However, larger plots require significantly more computing resources to generate (one k=33 plot requires much more than twice the time and energy as two k=32 plots), which is why I'm trying to maximize the number of plots.

Comment: I've edited the question to make the goals more clear.

Answer (score 1):

This is a special case of the (unbounded) [knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem) with equal values and weights ($v_i=w_i$ for all items $i$).

With capacity $W=3725.29$, an optimal solution is $x=(13, 1, 1, 2)$, with optimal objective value $3725$.

With capacity $W=5587.94$, an optimal solution is $x=(0, 0, 13, 0)$, with optimal objective value $5587.4$.

Answer (score -2):

This website will do the calculations for you.

https://plot-plan.chia.foxypool.io/

The solution is:

| # k32 | # k33 | # k34 | Space Used |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 34 | 0 | 0 | 3700.458 GB (≈99.33%) |
| 28 | 3 | 0 | 3720.117 GB (≈99.86%) |
| 1 | 12 | 2 | 3722.631 GB (≈99.93%) |

This calculation is based on k32 plots being 108.837 GB, k33 plots being 224.227 GB and k34 plots being 461.535 GB

Comment: I'm already aware of this website. However, it does not take into account k=35 plots: the ending solution I used was 28 k=32 plots plus one k=35 plot, which equals 3723.3 GiB, a higher proportion than any here.

Comment: Also, I'm looking for a general solution, i.e. a mathematical overview of how the site works.